# Free function in c

Tags: c

I have allocated memory to some data type and assigned some value. Now using `free` is the data in the memory deleted or not? What is use of using `free` if the data assigned is not deleted? Can anyone help me out? Ex:

```
int *arr;
arr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*1000);
assert(arr!=NULL);
/*Some operation*/

arr[123]=354;
//some operations

printf("%d",*(arr+123));
//calling some funcs

free(arr);

printf("\n%d",*(arr+123));
```

Comment: What is the connection between `arr` and `arr2`? This is very confused.

Comment: What you are doing is undefined behavior.  If it is printing a reasonable value, then you should consider that a coincidence.

Comment: See this answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work?lq=1

Comment: Side note: With `arr=malloc(1000*sizeof(*arr))` you don't have to repeat the type the pointer points to. This will be much more maintainable in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know if C function free is working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334132/how-to-know-if-c-function-free-is-working)

Answer (score 5):

The point of `free` is to make the memory you allocated available for following calls to `malloc`. It does not guarantee that the buffer passed to it is wiped in any way.

In fact, what you're doing is provoking **undefined behavior**; accessing a buffer that has been `free`'d might give the value that was previously stored in it, or any other value, or it might crash your program, or do anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "delete" things from memory.

What `free()` does is it *reclaims*  the memory, so that it can be recycled by a future call to `malloc()`.

You cannot legally dereference a pointer that you got from `malloc()` (or any other dynamic allocation call) after calling `free()` on it. Doing so invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

By using malloc you set aside a specified number of bytes to be used for what ever you want. Returned is an address to the area. The memory area is also flagged in a special table as occupied meaning it can't be reserved by another process or another malloc.

When you free the allocated memory the area is flagged as free, but the data is not erased. If you want to erase the data you'll have to do a memset or manually loop and set data to 0 or some other value **before you free it**.

As mentioned by others the operation on free memory is undefined.

A short introduction to how memory *can* be arranged. Look i.e. at heap:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/14268 or Fig 1. at bottom of this comment: [Strange global variable behaviour, once variable name is changed issue disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839969/strange-global-variable-behaviour-once-variable-name-is-changed-issue-disappear/9859393#9859393)

I have written some more about the malloc process itself here:
[Can some explain the performance behavior of the following memory allocating C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096294/can-some-explain-the-performance-behavior-of-the-following-memory-allocating-c-p/10214527#10214527) where also virtual vs. physical memory, pages etc are some of the points.